# Trying to open a terminal bash, from within terminal, with a specific, pre-made layout

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, osx-yosemite

I'm using a mac and I've got a automatic terminal window opening up at login, I would like to make this window execute a command, that will then open up another terminal window, with a layout that I've already made earlier and with full screen. I know that you can open another window with: `open -a Terminal "pwd"`, but how do I add arguments for a custom layout? I haven't seen any way to solve this, have you got ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "custom layout" exactly? A profile for the terminal window? A specific location for the terminal windows on the screen?

Comment: I'm sorry I stated this wrongly, but it's in the terminal preferences, They call it profiles. There are some standard ones but I would like to use another one I created myself.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/144207 ?

Comment: This is what I was looking for thank you! But it isn't totally complete tho, I'm glad to have this, but do you know how I could then do this on fullscreen? or isn't that possible?

Comment: If "full screen" isn't a profile option and there isn't a command line option for `Terminal` for it then no, not offhand. I don't really use OS X.

Comment: Ok thank you very much! I don't think it's possible to automatically enter fullscreen, but I'm pleased already! Thanks to you Etan!